# How can I make my Hapi route wait for data before returning a value?

Tags: node.js, async-await, hapi.js

I am using Hapi.js and have a route that I want to use to fetch data and then return a result.

I have tried to use async/await, but I must be doing something wrong because while the function I am calling eventually prints a result to the console, the route is returning without waiting for that function to return a value.

```
'use strict';

const Hapi = require('@hapi/hapi');
const HandyStorage = require('handy-storage');
var ethBalance ='';

// Connection to public blockchain via Infura.io
const Web3 = require("web3");
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/cf44bc52af3743bcad5f0b66813f8740"));

// Initialize Handy Storage
const storage = new HandyStorage({
    beautify: true
});

//Get ETH address from Handy Storage
storage.connect('./preferences.json');
var walletAddress = storage.state.wallet;

// Get wallet balance
const getWalletBalance = async () => {

    web3.eth.getBalance(`${walletAddress}`, async function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
        console.log('There was an error: ' + err);
        return ({ error: 'The wallet balance call failed.' });
        } else {
            ethBalance = await web3.utils.fromWei(result, "ether");
            console.log("This should be first: The wallet balance via API call is " + ethBalance + " ETH.");
            return ethBalance; // I expect the walletbalance route to wait for this to be returned
        }
    });
};

// API Server
const init = async () => {

    // Connection settings
    const server = Hapi.server({
        port: 3000,
        host: 'localhost'
    });

    // Get wallet balance
    server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/walletbalance/',
        handler: async (request, h) => {
            let result = null;
            try {
                result = await getWalletBalance();
                console.log('This should be second, after the getWalletBalance function has printed to the console.'); // this prints first, so await isn't working as expected
                return ({ ethBalance: result });
            } catch (err) {
                console.log('Error in walletbalance route');
            }
        }
    });

    // 404 error handling
    server.route({
        method: '*',
        path: '/{any*}',
        handler: function (request, h) {

            return ({
                message: 'Error!'
            });
        }
    });

    await server.start();
    console.log('Server running on %s', server.info.uri);
};

process.on('unhandledRejection', (err) => {
    console.log(err);
    process.exit(1);
});

init();
```

Any idea where I have gone wrong here? This is the first time I have used async/await.

ETA: My console looks like this:

```
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
Server running on http://localhost:3000
This should be second, after the getWalletBalance function has printed to the console.
This should be first: The wallet balance via API call is 4061.894069996147660079 ETH.
```

And this is the JSON I get back when I use the wallet balance route:

```
{}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer I was given, I was able to get the results I wanted with this:

```
'use strict';

const Hapi = require('@hapi/hapi');
const HandyStorage = require('handy-storage');
var ethBalance ='';

// Connection to public blockchain via Infura.io
const Web3 = require("web3");
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/cf44bc52af3743bcad5f0b66813f8740"));

// Initialize Handy Storage
const storage = new HandyStorage({
    beautify: true
});

//Get ETH address from Handy Storage
storage.connect('./preferences.json');
var walletAddress = storage.state.wallet;

// Get wallet balance
async function getWalletBalance(){
    let ethBalance = await web3.eth.getBalance(`${walletAddress}`);
      if (ethBalance.err) { 
        console.log('error in the called function');
        } else {
        return ethBalance;
  }
}

// API Server
const init = async () => {

    // Connection settings
    const server = Hapi.server({
        port: 3000,
        host: 'localhost'
    });

    // Get wallet balance
    server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/walletbalance/',
        handler: async (request, h) => {
            try {
                const result = await getWalletBalance();
                const ethBalanceInWei = web3.utils.fromWei(result, "ether");
                return ({ balance: ethBalanceInWei });
            } catch (err) {
                console.log('Error in walletbalance route');
            }
        }
    });

    // 404 error handling
    server.route({
        method: '*',
        path: '/{any*}',
        handler: function (request, h) {

            return ({
                message: 'Error!'
            });
        }
    });

    await server.start();
    console.log('Server running on %s', server.info.uri);
};

process.on('unhandledRejection', (err) => {
    console.log(err);
    process.exit(1);
});

init();
```

Thank you for the help! That got me going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your `getWalletBalance` function is using multiple concepts. callback style functions and inside that you are using await. I have restructured your code a little bit. Hopefully that should fix the issue which you are facing.

```
'use strict';

const Hapi = require('@hapi/hapi');
const HandyStorage = require('handy-storage');
var ethBalance ='';

// Connection to public blockchain via Infura.io
const Web3 = require("web3");
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/cf44bc52af3743bcad5f0b66813f8740"));

// Initialize Handy Storage
const storage = new HandyStorage({
    beautify: true
});

//Get ETH address from Handy Storage
storage.connect('./preferences.json');
var walletAddress = storage.state.wallet;

function getWalletBalance() {
  return Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    web3.eth.getBalance(`${walletAddress}`, (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log('There was an error: ' + err);
        reject({ error: 'The wallet balance call failed.' });
        } else {
          resolve(result);
        }
    });
  });
}

// API Server
const init = async () => {

    // Connection settings
    const server = Hapi.server({
        port: 3000,
        host: 'localhost'
    });

    // Get wallet balance
    server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/walletbalance/',
        handler: async (request, h) => {
            try {
                const result = await getWalletBalance();
                ethBalance = await web3.utils.fromWei(result, "ether");
                return ethBalance;
            } catch (err) {
                console.log('Error in walletbalance route');
            }
        }
    });

    // 404 error handling
    server.route({
        method: '*',
        path: '/{any*}',
        handler: function (request, h) {

            return ({
                message: 'Error!'
            });
        }
    });

    await server.start();
    console.log('Server running on %s', server.info.uri);
};

process.on('unhandledRejection', (err) => {
    console.log(err);
    process.exit(1);
});

init();
```

Comment: Thank you. That did not work:

`[nodemon] starting `node stack.js`

`Server running on http://localhost:3000`

`Error in walletbalance route`

`Debug: internal, implementation, error `

    `Error: handler method did not return a value, a promise, or throw an error`

But it gives me an idea of what to look at - apparently I have the Promise syntax all wrong.

Comment: The code wouldn’t work without modifications but glad that it gave you an idea